# looking for regex to match some part of URL

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex to match some part of URL to redirect my pages accordingly.

I have googled it with no luck.

EX:

### http://www.somesite.com/cat1/cat2/

In this i am looking to match any word or char after the domain name, so it would be /cat1/cat2/

### http://www.somesite.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/

In this i am looking to match any word or char after the domain name, so it would be /cat1/cat2/cat3/

---

looking for 2 diff regex to match this kind of url. First regex that matches only 2 category and second regex that matches only 3 category.

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: C#. I am already having a rewrite rule config file for my application. so i am not looking for any solution other then REGEX.. my company would not allow me to use other solution. thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for the first case, with the desired part in the first capturing group:

```
^http://[^/]+(/(?:[^/]*/){2})$
```

Change the `{2}` part to `{3}` for the second case.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But when i am checking online your regex does not match any url. i might be wrong. this is the site i used http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Try it now. I initially assumed that you were using JavaScript, so I escaped the forward slashes. That may not be how it works in C#.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. actually i do not want to match the whole URL..just need to match /cat1/cat2/ and /cat1/cat2/cat3/ from URL..can you please revise your regex and let me know ...thanks

Comment: The first capturing group contains the part you want. You can access it using `myMatch.Groups[1]`, where myMatch is the Match object (I think; I don't use C#, myself).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty simple.

First regex would be like :
    http://.+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/

I'll let you guess what the second regex is.

Comment: your regex is matching both http://somesite.com/cat1/cat2 and also http://somesite.com/cat1/cat2/cat3

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, regexs do not support inverse matching. That means, you cannot write a regex that matches what is NOT in the regex (if I'm wrong, please someone correct me on this). That being said, you could use this:

```
^http:\/\/[^\/]+\/(.*)
```

Using grouping, you can match whatever comes after your URL domain. So, in this case, what you are looking for would be fetcheable through $1 (the group represented by the brackets at the end of the regex). Another important thing is the ^ in the beginning of the regex. This way you won't catch URL strings passed as query parameters of your URL.

Comment: by the way, this will catch everything, including the query part of the url. if you only want to get the relative path, then you'll have to complete it for the case you catch a '?' character.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. actually i do not want to match the whole URL..just need to match /cat1/cat2/ and /cat1/cat2/cat3/ from URL..can you please revise your regex and let me know ...thanks

Comment: ok, so what you want is the segment. ^http:\/\/[^\/]+\/([^?]*) will do.

Answer (score 0):

you can get path name from `windwo.location.pathname`

```
var path = window.location.pathname
```

after getting this `path` you can get path using `split('/');`